# Working with $_POST from ajax in symfony controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm beginner to symfony.
I have a twig template with 2 buttons that calls an external .js that executes an ajax call.

Button 1 calls function 'delete', and this is the js code:

```
    var path = $("#abc").attr("data-path");
 /*grabs it from some div in the twig template.. <div id="abc" data-path="{{path('delete')}}"></div>*/

    function delete(n){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",     
          url: path,
          data: {id : n},
          "success":function(data){
          alert('ok');
          }
          });
    }
```

Button 2 calls function 'edit' which is the same code except that the 'url' goes to another 'action', and the 'data' is not a json, (it is data: formData)

Routing.yml for function delete is:

```
    delete:
        pattern:  /delete
        defaults: {_controller: TPMainBundle:Default:delete }
```

And this is the controller action:

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
 $id = $_POST['id']; 
 /*other code to work with doctrine making queries to delete from database*/ 
}
```

(The js code is from a webpage done without symfony and it works fine)

I was told the right way to retrieve the POST in the action, reglardless it was whether a json or formData, was using the same that I used in PHP:

```
 $id = $_POST['id'];
```

Here, I have 2 problems.

First, I don't know if this is correct because it doesn't work.

Second, I don't know how can I know if i'm retrieving the POST OK !!

When I did this without symfony, I checked if I was getting the POST with the command 'fwrite', because the ajax went to a PHP file instead of an Action, and then with the command fwrite I created a .txt file with the output of an echo to see if the $_POST was recovered or not.

But here in symfony I don't know how to check it, so I'm driving myself crazy.. trying to implement the solutions I read without being sure if they work..

and with the extra problem that since I'm newbie for me it's a bit confusing trying to install some external bundles for debug.  Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct approach for acessing post or get params is using Symfony's `Request` object. You can pass it as an argument of a controller action, or retrieve it from the controller directly. Here's two examples:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $id = $request->get('id');
    }
}
```

Without passing the `Request` as a parameter:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->get('id');
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works if I don't pass Request as a parameter but, why doesn't it work with Request as a parameter?   I'm not missing the  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;      Is there a special code if I have to get a formData which as a type File within ?

Comment: I updated the code to include the type casting. There's no additional code needed on this part, but if you are sending files through AJAX you may have a bit extra work. For this simple delete example, the code above is enough.

Comment: I get it, it was the typecasting the reason with Request didn't worked, thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony you get your POST data from the current Request object (That's how we do it in Symfony), one way to get the current Request object is by adding $request variable as first parameter in your action function.
Your action function could be like this:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request)
{
    //check if our POST var is there
    if($request->request->has('id')){
        //it's there
        $id = $request->request->get('id');
        /*other code to work with doctrine making queries to delete from database*/ 
    }else{
        //it's not there!
    }

}
```

Regarding installing third party bundle, use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to do this task for you, and don't forget to add the class path of the installed bundle to `$bundles` array in `AppKernal` class. Follow this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html) to know how to do this.

Comment: Thank you Zain, but it's not working, I added

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;  

 and for checking I simplified by removing the 'if' and the 'else' clause, but the firebug says it's a 500 error message in the deleteAction.. thank you for the link !!!  (sorry, I don't know why the </br> are not being shown in my answer)

Comment: Can you see where the error occurred in your code (class name and line number) from firebug?

Comment: Use double space instead of </br> for line break

Comment: Nothing, it just says:  POST http://localhost/TP/web/app_dev.php/delete 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Check response body in firebug to locate the error, Symfony error page contain these information.

Comment: mm.. the full error information from firebug is "POST http://localhost/TP/web/app_dev.php/delete 500 (Internal Server Error)c.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.4.2.min.js:130borrar @ abmc.js:126onclick @ home:1" but the error doesn't happen when I try without passing request has a parameter like:  $id = $this->getRequest()->get('id');    The symfony debug is not showing any exception

Comment: Gotcha, the code worked if I wrote (Request $request) instead of just ($request)  Thank you very much for your patience !

Comment: Did you check 'net' panel? there you can see the ajax request and response. If you cannot see the response, check `app/log/dev.log` file, the error details will be there

Comment: Yesss...  In the dev.log:   "Controller "TP\MainBundle\Controller\DefaultController::deleteAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one)."  Thank you again, it's a nice tip !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Extra tip for people who comes from PHP and doesn't know how to check if they are retrieving the POST or not:  - send it to a .php

```
public function deleteAction($request)
{  
    $id = SOME RETRIEVED CODE YOU AREN'T SURE YOU ARE RETRIEVING THE RIGHT WAY;

/*you can send this variable to a view, symfony allows you to use .php files but you have to name their extension as html.php not just .php*/

return $this->render('TPMainBundle:Default:test.html.php', array('id' => $id));

}
```

And then, in that view:

```
<?php

echo $id;

$myfile = fopen("somename.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = 'Id is: '.$id;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

This will generate a .txt
So, you can open the .txt and check if you have recovered the DATA or not!

The file will be located inside the 'web' folder..

The other tips is to check the 'app/log/dev.log' thanks @Zain Saqer